# C# использование сторонних классов в проекте

Tags: c#, библиотеки

Нужно написать небольшой функционал по работе с жестким диском. Сама суть программы не важна. Важно, что большая часть классов и методом используется из сторонней библиотеки: https://github.com/DiscUtils/DiscUtils
В данном проекте нет конкретно статичных или динамических библиотек, все структурировано по классам.

Вопрос: как в новом проекте использовать методы и классы из данного проекта, я понимаю как использовать именно библиотеки shared static, а как использовать классы без переноса всего вышеуказанного проекта в свой не понимаю.

Comment: ну я думаю юзануть библиотеку (если такая имеется) или открыть проект и по нему сформировать либу....еще как вариант просто использовать несколько решений в одном проекте

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц, пока тестирую свой код как раз как новое решение, но при этом интересно как можно использовать весь проект каким-либо подключением к проекту, возможно ли вообще это

Comment: 1) Склонировать и добавить ссылку на файл проекта к себе в солюшен 2) Форкнуть и добавить как git submodule, если используете git 3) Склонировать, собрать и добавить как библиотеку

Comment: Подключите эту библиотеку как nuget пакет. 
Она доступна на www.nuget.org.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/DiscUtils/

Comment: @Vyacheslav Benedichuk, спасибо! То что надо!

Comment: @VyacheslavBenedichuk имхо, достойно ответа

Comment: @tym32167 да, спасибо. Напишу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего подключить стороннюю библиотеку через nuget пакет. 
Конкретно эта библиотека уже доступна на nuget.org https://www.nuget.org/packages/DiscUtils/

Для некоторых популярных библиотек бывает, что в nuget они доступны в разных вариантах от разных разработчиков. В таких случаях имеет смысл выбирать официальный релиз или наиболее свежую версию.

Если вдруг на nuget.org библиотеки не оказалось и в документации нет ссылок на альтернативные источники, можно собрать пакет самостоятельно и установить его из локальной папки. Для этого нужно будет создать папку, в которую поместить собранные nupkg файлы. Указать эту папку как источник пакетов в Visual Studio и выбрать его при установке пакета.